# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: Running setup.py install for sha256 ... error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sha256

всем привет, при установке библиотеки bipwallet возникает ошибка:

```
Running setup.py install for sha256 ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую MacOs и python3.9.7

пробовал на Linux и на windows и все тоже самое

пробовал и

```
pip install bipwallet
```

и

```
pip3 install bipwallet
```

```
brew install bipwallet
```

и скачивал архивом
но все безуспешно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так же пробовал из под рута но не помогает

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: А зачем вы обрезали самое важное в конце? Там же где-то ошибка и должна быть напечатана, но вы всё отрезали.

Comment: добавил
тут ничего важного

Comment: Use python 3.9 and Visual Studio Build Tools 2022. Chack this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29846087/error-microsoft-visual-c-14-0-is-required-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/43826967#43826967